# Theming a Datasheet View

Tags: 2010, branding, datasheet

In my custom theme the background of my theme is a dark grey. When I go onto a datasheet view of a list the dark grey is used as the background colour. Is it possible to target only the datasheet view object and make the background white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
body
{
    background: #1F2021;
}
```

becomes

```
body
{
    background: #fff;
}

form#aspnetForm
{
    background-color: #1F2021;
}
```